# .htaccess Rewrite problems for site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So my site is moddinghq.com when you go to it and click register it takes you to a page and says no input specified. ive been told the problem is the .htaccess but not how to fix it. SO heres the code:

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http: //%1/$1 [R=301,L]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

If someone could tell me whats wrong that would be great

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be is that you are using REQUEST_URI, and in [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) say:

"REQUEST_URI
The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as as its own variable named QUERY_STRING."

I think that you have to use QUERY_STRING, how has all the query string with the information.